# Creating an app only for signing transactions that I create through a website

Tags: transactions, ethers.js, ethereum-wallet-dapp

I want to create an app that signs transactions that I initiate through a web app. An example for this is open sea that lets you connect to any wallet on your mobile device and sign transactions on the mobile device while the web app initiates all the transactions and you can view all the assets on the web app. Any resources on how I maybe able to start making this?

Some of the libraries that I am working with is: ethers.js for mobile and web app.

Comment: Did you check WalletConnect protocol?